# How do I undo syntax highlighting for special characters in Vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

The default behavior in Vim is to syntax highlight special characters such as Numbers, booleans, etc. However when working with comments I find this to be a major distraction since Vim is highlighting them by default. I'd like to keep any syntax coloring in a comment to be the same all across the board. (in my case, light gray)

What is the colorscheme or vimrc setting to maintain a a consistent comment color?[image]

Also `unlet c_comment_strings` does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is not about particular color scheme. This is about syntax matching rule that allows to find strings/numbers even inside comments. So it depends upon a language.

For C/C++ it is governed by existence of `c_comment_strings` variable (see also `:h c.vim`). And it is **not** a true default. That variable either intentionally defined in your vimrc or it comes from standard `defaults.vim`. In latter case you need to unlet it.

For other languages refer to Vim docs on a particular syntax.

Comment: I tried `unlet c_comment_strings` in my vimrc file and in the editor however it did not work.

Comment: @in-just MCVE = Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example. "It did not work" means nothing.

Comment: I input the recommended command into Vim and the syntax is still being highlighted.

Comment: @in-just Obviously, that's not how it works. Neither that you were told to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant then. Is there way to edit the `defaults.vim` outside of the vimrc file?